# Как использовать внешний скрипт в Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome

Первые шаги с Chrome App упёрлись в стену: как загрузить внешний скрипт в приложение?

Нужен api ВКонтакта. План-Б сохранить сегодняшнюю версию статично, но это не супер.

**upd.** не нужен этот API, я ошибся. Просто ajax запросы на `https://api.vk.com`